# Error enabling canonical livepatch

Tags: command-line, canonical-livepatch

I would like to enable Canonical Livepatch on my personal computer. After installing it, bash tells me that Livepatch isn't available for Ubuntu 21.10, which is the version I'm using.

How do I enable it?

Comment: The information is correct. Livepatch is available for LTS releases only.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to this as Livepatch is only meant for Long-Term Support versions (LTS).

*Side note:* There's no need for Livepatch if you're using a Laptop or PC...It's only meant for Ubuntu servers, and that's exactly why it's not available for non-LTS versions; You're going to use LTS on a server because it has long-term support, security, and maintenance updates.

If you are insistant on Livepatch, then you must change to an LTS version.